# Using text-transform property inside a span tag inside an H1 tag

Tags: css

I know that `<span>` tags are allowed inside of `<H1>` tags. However, when I style said span with the text-transform property, it doesn't work - while other properties such as color, size, font-family, etc. do work. Why?

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  }
h1 span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Title - <span>something else</span></h1>
```

Comment: It looks capitalised to me. What isn't working?

Comment: It does work. I think you want `uppercase` instead of `capitalize`.

Comment: Changing it to `uppercase` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be working just fine. `capitalize` will capitalize the **first letter** of each word in the `<span>`, which it is. If you want **all caps** then use `uppercase`.

```css
h1 span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[`text-transform` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform).